# Mathematical Derivation of the Condition of Equilibrium of a Rigid Body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium, rigid-body-dynamics

We know that for a body to be in equilibrium, the resultant force and resultant torque must be both zero. The question is: can we *derive* this from more fundamental principles mathematically, such as Newton's laws or Lagrangian formalism?

Answer (score 0):

The ideas below are very easy to be formalised using equations.

Firstly, suppose that we have zero net force and torque. Force = rate of change of momentum. The internal forces are pairwise opposite due to Newton's 3rd law, and hence sum to zero. The external forces also sum to zero. As a result, rate of change of total momentum is zero. Therefore, the centre of mass is moving at constant velocity.

We may now change to the centre of mass frame, which is also an inertial frame. Resultant torque = rate of change of angular momentum for each small piece of mass in the rigid body. Moments due to internal forces are of course pairwise opposite and sum to zero. Moment of external forces sum to zero. Therefore, the rate of change of total angular momentum is zero.  The body is rotating at constant speed.

Conversely, suppose the centre of mass is moving at constant velocity and the body is rotating at constant angular velocity about this point. Then again, internal forces sum to zero, and since the momentum does not change, all forces sum to zero. Therefore, the external forces must sum to zero.

As for torque, the same argument applies: since the rate of change of angular momentum is zero, so is the resultant torque.